# How to get the result in this way?about determinant

Tags: differential-geometry

In theory of surfaces using the fact that $\vec v \in T_p(M)$=$\alpha\vec x_u+\beta\vec x_v$ and  $ S_p(\vec v)\times \vec v=\vec 0, $

deduce that a nonzero tangent vector can  be  a principal direction vector if and only if:

$$\begin{vmatrix}\beta^2&-\alpha\beta &\alpha^2\\E &F&G\\e&f&g\end{vmatrix} =0$$

where $ E,F,G,e,f,g $ are coefficients of first and second fundamental forms.

I know how to get this result but not in this way.  Could someone can help me step by step? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that you know how to get this result but not in this way? What *do* you know how to do?

Comment: My steps:Principal direction$\to$orthogonal and conjugate.du:dv$\to$principal direction;$\delta u:\delta v\to$another on principal direction.By definition,$\Rightarrow\begin{cases}Edu\delta u+F(du\delta v+dv\delta u)+Gdv\delta v=0\\ldu\delta u+m(du\delta v+dv\delta u)+ndv\delta v=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}(Edu+Fdv)\delta u+(Fdu+Gdv)\delta v=0\\(ldu+mdv)\delta u+(mdu+ndv)\delta v=0\end{cases}$
,and$\delta u,\delta v$ doesn't all equal zero.$\Rightarrow$$\begin{vmatrix}Edu+Fdv & Fdu+Gdv\\ldu+mdv & mdu+ndv\end{vmatrix} =0\Rightarrow(Fl-Em)du^2+(Gl-En)dudv+(Gm-Fn)dv^2=0$

Comment: Then we can get same result:$$\begin{vmatrix}\beta^2&-\alpha\beta &\alpha^2\\E &F&G\\e&f&g\end{vmatrix} =0$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a proof I would give has more modern notation (rather than using the $\delta u$ and $du$, etc.), but it's essentially the same. To say that $v=\alpha x_u+\beta x_v$ is a principal direction is to say that $$\begin{bmatrix}E&F\\F&G\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} e&f\\f&g \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix} = \lambda\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$$
for some scalar $\lambda$. This means that the vectors
$$\begin{bmatrix} e&f\\f&g \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \begin{bmatrix}E&F\\F&G\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$$
are parallel, which gives 
$$\left| \begin{matrix} E\alpha + F\beta & F\alpha + G\beta \\ e\alpha + f\beta & f\alpha + g\beta \end{matrix}\right| = 0.$$
Expanding this out gives the $3\times 3$ determinant in question.

Comment: Oh!Thank you!After what you write,I know how do to that.